# How to place a text on a curved surface?

Tags: modifiers

[image]i am quite new in Blender, I was trying to put a text over a curved surface such as a UV Sphere, I go for the Shrinkwarp modifier but the text looks not perfect, there are some vertices showing which are not the surface, making a bad aspect. How can I make it better, is there another way? Thanks for the help

Comment: you can put it onto the sphere texture

Comment: Yea I tried by doing that but the text looks like not uniform with the surface, how can I explain that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your text mesh isn't retopologized. The triangles you're seeing are normal for Text to Mesh conversion, which creates a bunch of horribly topologized long skinny triangles. You'll need to retopo your text mesh

Comment: Solved it, thank you so much for helping  me solve the problem!!!